# GTK critical assertion error while launching

Tags: 16.04, gtk

Lately i have installed TrackVis Software tool but when ever i try to load GUI interface i am getting GTK_Critical error, kindly please let me know what exactly is the reason for this error and how can i solve it.

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~/Documents/TrackVis_v0.6.0.1_x86_64$ ./trackvis

(trackvis:26847): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(trackvis:26847): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(trackvis:26847): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(trackvis:26847): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(trackvis:26847): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a bug in either the TrackVis Software tool or in GTK itself, most likely the former.  Report it as a bug.